# Excel formula to check if a range of data are all exactly same

Tags: excel

I have a range of cell values. I want to check this range of values and return true if all the values are exactly the same and return false if at least 1 is not the same.

```
Range 1
Confirmed
Confirmed
Confirmed

Result= Confirmed

Range 2
Confirmed
Negotiation
Confirmed

Result = Varies
```

ETA:
Thanks simoco for the answer which I'm using now.  I have a follow-up question. How do I modify this formula to ignore blank cells instead of defaulting to FALSE? With your formula, when it evaluates a range of blank cells (that are waiting for input), it returns "Varies". I want it to return blank instead.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please explain what have you tried, and a little of data to make it reproducible it would be grate!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:A3,A1)=COUNTA(A1:A3),"Confirmed","Varies")
```

Comment: I think yours is better and simpler formula. Cheers!

Comment: How do i modify this formula to ignore blank cells instead of defaulting to FALSE? With the above formula, when it evaluates a range of blank cells (waiting for input), it returns "Varies". I want it to return blank as well.

Comment: try this one: `=IF(OR(COUNTIF(A1:A3,A1)=COUNTA(A1:A3),COUNTA(A1:A3)=0),"Confirmed","Varies")`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)

```
=IF(SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(A1:A3,A1:A3,0),MATCH(A1:A3,A1:A3,0))>0,1))=1,"Confirmed","Varies")
```

[image]